# Is there a way to use WUApiLib API in a UWP App?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an UWP App, and I need to list all the pending Windows Updates for the machine where mu App is running.

I know I can use WUApiLib for doing that in a WPF App, but I am not sure it is possible to do the same thing in an UWP App.

Is it possible?

If not, there is another way in UWP for searching and listing all the pending Windows Updates in an UWP App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately,the WUApiLib is not supported.But there is a workaround.You can write a WPF app and package your WPF app to UWP by **Desktop Bridge**.Here is the Desktop Bridge [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-root).